# One Page Checkout begin at top of screen on next

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I use a vertical one page checkout methode, so that the steps are taken vertical.

When the first billing page is filled in, I want to begin all next steps at the top of the page.

I edit skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js and replaced the gotoSection as follow.

Default:

```
gotoSection: function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {

    if (reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
    }
    this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-' + section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-' + section);
    if(!reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.resetPreviousSteps();
    }
},
```

Replaced with:

```
gotoSection: function(section, reloadProgressBlock) {

    if (reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.reloadProgressBlock(this.currentStep);
    }
    this.currentStep = section;
    var sectionElement = $('opc-'+section);
    sectionElement.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection('opc-'+section);
    if(!reloadProgressBlock) {
        this.resetPreviousSteps();
    }
    jQuery("html, body").delay(10).animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#opc-"+section).offset().top }, 50);
},
```

That does work for the scroll, but it begin to early on the page and I need to edit it because we have a fixed header.

How can I edit this code, so that it is placed correctly with our fixed header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line, I guess you have to substract the fixed header's height from the scrolling position where you want to go.

So, assuming your header is something like `<div id="header">...</div>`, change the line to this:

```
jQuery("html, body").delay(10).animate({scrollTop: (jQuery("#opc-"+section).offset().top - jQuery('#header').height()) }, 50);
```

Note the `jQuery('#header').height()` I have added.

**UPDATE**

If you need to scroll further, you can simply substract a higher number from the target position. I put the target position in a variable for clarification:

```
// calculate the offset, note the new "- 50" at the end
var targetOffset = jQuery("#opc-"+section).offset().top
                       - jQuery('#header').height() - 50;
jQuery("html, body").delay(10).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 50);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is much better, but it is still not good enough. It still needs to scroll higher. How can I set it higher?

Comment: edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

checkout/onepage.phtml

```
checkout.gotoSection = function (section, reloadProgressBlock) {
    Checkout.prototype.gotoSection.call(this, section, reloadProgressBlock);
    $('opc-' + section).scrollTo();
};
```

below

```
var checkout = new Checkout(....);
```